# how to add to angular ng-model values from two inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have an angular application.
How i can to add in one ng-model values from two or more inputs.
This is my input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="type" ng-model="flat.flatData.type" placeholder="Flat type" >
```

In this case all working fine, but i want add some more inputs. In this model i want to have an array.
In the result i want something like this:

- first input value = type1
- second input value = type2
- thirs input value = type3

and so on.
Finally i want to have an array in this model [type1, type2, type3]

Comment: Separate inputs, and a controller method to combine them all into an array.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm don't understand( Maybe you have example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
ok, I confess I didn't get your question before but I think I do now. This is what it sounds like you're trying to do:

html

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in vm.numbers track by $index">
  <input type="text" ng-model="item" ng-change="vm.updateSum()">
</div>
<button ng-click="vm.addInput()">+</button>
<br><br>
array:
<div>{{vm.numbers}}</div>
sum:
<div>{{vm.sum}}</div>
```

js:

```
var vm = this;
vm.numbers = [99,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
vm.sum = 0;
vm.updateSum = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < vm.numbers.length; i++) {
    vm.sum = vm.sum + vm.numbers[i];
  }
}
vm.updateSum();

vm.addInput = function(){
  vm.numbers[vm.numbers.length] = 0;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XiI8Sc?p=preview

---

---

old answer:

This would be a prime use case for a directive, or perhaps a couple of directives, based on the flow you need. A similar use case that is pretty common and has a lot of answers is the case where a form needs to compare two fields and make sure they're the same (e.g. "type you password twice" for registering). I recommend looking that one up.

In the meanwhile, you'll want to mock out the functionality one way or another, so here's a plnkr with the basics working via a $watch

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  $scope.$watch('vm.one', function() {
    vm.three = parseInt(vm.one) + parseInt(vm.two);
    console.log('one change');
  });
  $scope.$watch('vm.two', function() {
    vm.three = parseInt(vm.one) + parseInt(vm.two);
  });
});
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.one"><br><br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.two"><br><br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.three">

  <div>{{vm.one}}</div>
  <div>{{vm.two}}</div>
  <div>{{vm.three}}</div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8J7X0p?p=info

Comment: thanks for answer. But user can add, for example, 10 inputs, and i would save it to the one array in database. Maybe you have some examples?

Comment: In this input i would have a string, maybe you know how to modify this code?

Comment: if any of the inputs are strings js will just smush them all together, so instead of 2 + 2 = 4 ; '2' + 2 = '22'. You can account for that by using parseInt('2') + parseInt(2) = 4